# Use of 'would' in the past, that is not conditional

Tags: past-tense, would

I know there have been similar questions, but I'm curious as to the stylistic acceptance of this usage, as it often seems pointless to me. Example:
'Due to dwindling ratings, and the decline of music based TV in favor of online services, MTV would announce the cancellation of TRL on September 15 2008'

Comment: Past habits – 'used to', 'would' and the past simple  - https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/past-habits-used-to-would-and-the-past-simple - http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode69/languagepoint.shtml - http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-difference-between-used-to-and-would

Comment: That's called [future in the past](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html), and it's kind of the only way to express this, so it's not pointless.